# TRIM specific column names in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "User" with 5 columns 'id','firstname','lastname','age','email'.

Is it possible to execute this sql command?

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(firstname,lastname,email)) FROM User
```

All i need to select is the 3 columns that are trimmed.

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Are you trying to write less code and get more...? you need to LTRIM RTRIM each column - no way around it. So you might as well mark one of the answers with a tick mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle each column separately, as in:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(firstname)) as firstname,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(lastname)) as lastname,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(email)) as email
FROM [User]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to trim each field separately

```
select ltrim(rtrim(firstname)), ltrim(rtrim(lastname)), ltrim(rtrim(email))
from User
```

Comment: how about this 'SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(*)) FROM User'

Comment: these functions can only be applied to a field, not a row.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, thanks for pointing that out. answer has been updated

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(FirstName)) AS FirstName,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(LastName)) AS LastName,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)) AS Email
FROM    User
```

You need to do TRIM all the column separately.